# Building a typescript library

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc

I am starting a new library in Typescript and React.

But there something wrong on my tsconfig, because when I look at `dist` directory, there is only the typescript definitions, and **no** code in javascript, all code was removed!

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "lib",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "exclude": ["lib/**/*.spec.tsx", "lib/**/*.stories.tsx", "lib/**/*.styles.tsx", "lib/settings/*.ts", "dist/**/*"]
}
```

Here a example of the output file (in dist directory)

Button.d.ts

```
import React from 'react';
export declare class ButtonProps {
    label: string;
    buttonStyle: 'default' | 'primary';
    disabled: boolean;
    iconLeft: string;
    iconRight: string;
}
declare const Button: React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps>;
export default Button;
//# sourceMappingURL=Button.d.ts.map
```

And there is no code in any of the other files!

[image]

What I did wrong? All code was gone on build (building with `tsc`), there only the type definitions.

Comment: `"emitDeclarationOnly": true,` appears to be the problem

Comment: turn off `emitDeclarationOnly` https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#emitDeclarationOnly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing the tsconfig to

```
{
  "exclude": ["lib/**/*.spec.tsx", "lib/**/*.stories.tsx", "lib/**/*.styles.tsx", "dist/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDirs": ["lib"],
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```